# How to convert decimal numbers stored as characters in a string to doubles?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, strtod

New to programming, I'm looping through a postfix string and trying to retrieve the numbers individually, I only need one at a time.

Initially I wrote this for integers and just did "- '0'", however, I now need to try and make it compatible for decimal numbers.

An example of my integer conversion is below, how could I adapt this?

```
int i;
char postfix[] = "4 3 +";

for (i=0; i<strlen(postfix); i++) {
    if (isalnum(postfix[i])) {
        int value=(postfix[i]-'0');
        printf("%d\n", value);
    }
}

4
3
```

e.g. how to evaluate when

```
char postfix[] = "1.2 3.4 +"
```

storing the value as a double

Comment: If you only want to solve "a b op", you can use `sscanf(postfix, "%f %f %s", &a, &b, c)`, and you get the values in floats `a`, `b`, and in `c[0]` the operator. For a more complicated expression, you will need a stack data structure I think, and more complicated parsing

Comment: The [`strtod()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) function would probably be my choice, unless I could rely on exactly the "*x* *y* *op*" form for every case (for which I would probably choose [`s`]`scanf`).

Comment: Note also, by the way, that your approach for integers works only for non-negative, single-digit numbers, so I hesitate to call it a complete solution for the integer case.  There is, however, `strtod()`'s integer-oriented sibling [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) that you might consider instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    int i;
    double res;
    char *ptr1;
    char *ptr2;
    char postfix[] = "4.5 3.4 4.5 7.6 8.9 3.6 +";

    ptr1 = postfix;
    res = strtod(ptr1, &ptr2);
    
    
    while (res!= 0.0f )  // strtod() return 0.0 if double value is not found.
    {
        printf("Value in decimal is %lf\n",res);
        ptr1 = ptr2;
        res = strtod(ptr1, &ptr2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
Value in decimal is 4.500000
Value in decimal is 3.400000
Value in decimal is 4.500000
Value in decimal is 7.600000
Value in decimal is 8.900000
Value in decimal is 3.600000
```

Please see this link to know about `strtod() function` :https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtod()` to parse the string for a valid `double`.

`current == endptr` implies conversion failed.

```
char postfix[] = "4 3 +";
char *current = postfix;
char *endptr;

double v1 = strtod(current, &endptr);
if (current == endptr) TBD_code_handle_failure();
else current = endptr; 

double v2 = strtod(current, &endptr);
if (current == endptr) TBD_code_handle_failure();
else current = endptr; 

while (isspace((unsigned char) *current)) {  // skip white-space
  current++;
}

if (strchr("+-*/", *current) == NULL) {
  TBD_code_handle_failure(); // unexpected operator
}

printf("%g %g %c\n", v1, v2, *current);
```

---

Or ....

```
double v1, v2;
char oper;
if (sscanf(postfix, "%lf %lf %c", &v1, &v2, &oper) == 3) {
  ; // Success!
}
```